# die einen (at the beginning of a sentence)

Tags: article

I have heard the following in the TV series "How to Sell Drugs Online (Fast)":

> Die Tabletten gibt es in allen möglichen Formen und Farben. Alle mit unterschiedlichen Zusatzstoffen und unterschiedlichem MDMA-Gehalt. Die einen im besten Fall die Ganze Nacht wach halten und im schlechtesten Fall in die Notaufnahme  bringen.

I confirmed that I heard right by checking the German subtitles.

What does "die einen" mean? I initially though that "die" was a relative pronoun (even if it's oddly positioned at the beginning of the sentence), but then I don't understand how "einen" fits in the sentence. In other words, I'd say instead: Die Tabletten, die im besten Fall die ganze Nacht wach halten und im...

Another alternative meaning of "die einen" that would fit in this context is "the ones", but AFAIK that should be "diejenigen"?

Comment: Did you only hear the quoted text or is it from transcript or subtitles?

Comment: @Wolf Subtitles

Comment: So it would be better to start with something like "I read the following in the subtitles of the TV series ..."

Comment: @Wolf Maybe I wasn't clear in my last comment. I heard it and confirmed it with the subtitles. I'm not sure that is relevant to the question, but I have added it.

Comment: As it deals with an error in written grammar, it's important, [Torsten explains the details](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61844/5437).

Comment: I'd translate it as "*The pills come in all kinds of shapes and colors. Keeping you awake at night in the best case, and landing you at the emergency room in the worst case.*"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In spoken language it is sometimes hard to hear the clear borders of sentences. And spoken / colloquial language does not always follow grammatical rules.

You heard the part with "die einen..." as a standalone and separate sentence and probably the speaker emphasized it exactly that way.
If we try to find out, what that sentence would be when written down in a grammatically correct way then it is:

> Die Tabletten gibt es in allen möglichen Formen und Farben, alle mit unterschiedlichen Zusatzstoffen und unterschiedlichem MDMA-Gehalt **, die** *einen* im besten Fall die Ganze Nacht wach halten und im schlechtesten Fall in die Notaufnahme bringen.

So in reality we have a relative clause here:

> Tabletten [...] mit unterschiedlichen Zusatzstoffen [...], die *einen* die ganze Nacht wach halten.

Or, to give a complete translation:

> The pills come in all possible forms and colours, all with different addditional substances and different concentration of MDMA **that** hold *you* awake the whole night at best and bring you to emergency room at worst

There IS a word couple containing "die einen", but it is almost inseparable connected with "die anderen":

> **Die einen** halten dich die ganze Nacht wach, **die anderen** bringen dich in die Notaufnahme

Translated as:

> **Some** keep you awake the whole night, **others** bring you to emergency room

Addition -as requested in comments-:
An additional challenge here is the possible different meanings / declensions of *einen*: It can be the nominative plural of "ein" (as in my last example), but in this case it is the accusative singular of "einer" which itself is the masculinum form of "ein" and means "one".

Comment: Notice that this is spoken dialogue. I agree that your interpretation of a punctuation error makes more sense in written text, but I think a separated relative sentence isn't unnatural in colloquial speech.

Comment: You are right, it is ok in colloquial speech, but still "Die einen die ganze Nacht wach halten" is not a correct German sentence... and that makes it hard for some NON- German person to understand / translate it, as it is missing parts...

Comment: Great explanation. To avoid this kind of confusion is the reason why subordinate clauses in German must not stand alone.

Comment: But the relative clause isn't missing any parts. That *die* and *einen* are interpreted as subject and object has nothing to do with the spelling, but with the fact that the finite verb is in final position.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ok, sorry, I am out of school since 25 years... and back then we learned, that a relative clause can never stand alone. If today it is valid to have "Die einen die ganze Nacht wach halten" as a stand alone sentence, then I apologize for being wrong. But still it sound weird for me...

Comment: I'm just saying that the relative clause is complete and well-formed. The orthography doesn't change anything. (After all, language is also spoken.)

Comment: Ich denke, wir reden aneinander vorbei ;). You are right: of course, the sentence is absolutely well formed. It just cannot stand alone (in written language)... So it's not the sentence that is wrong but the punctuation. Should have been more precise...

Comment: Could you please add to the answer that "einen" here is the accusative masculine declension of the pronoun "einer", which means "one"/"you" in English? I only knew "einen" as the accusative masculine declension of the indefinite article "ein" and that prevented me from understanding the sentence meaning (as well as the fact that the relative clause oddly is in a separated sentence).

Comment: Is it understandable as I added it?

Comment: It's „dich”, not „Dich”.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you

Comment: Have you never uttered a sentence in conversation like "Was ich auch hoffen will" or "Den hier keiner kennt"? It is perfectly normal. This would be a great answer if it didn't start with this stuff about punctuation.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Then probably "punctuation" is the wrong word here in this context and it should be intonation / phrasing / emphasis. OP wrote, that he cross checked with subtitles and I -probably wrongly- assumed that the text was copied from subtitles... I will rephrase that first paragraph, but need some time to think about it as I don't want to invalidate the given upvotes...

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Does this first paragraph fit better in you eyes?

Comment: I think that it is just an everyday pattern in spoken language to add a Nebensatz or adverbial or other part of the sentence a few seconds later, after a short pause and some thinking. So if this is transcribed with periods, as it is here, you basically get a number of utterances that are separated by periods even though they are grammatically the same sencence.
"Sie ist mir fremdgegangen. Mit Marvin. Wiederholt. Ohne mit der Wimper zu zucken. Den ich ja schon immer gehasst habe. Seit der Grundschule."

Answer (score 9):

*Einen* is the accusative of *man*.

> *Man* wird von den Tabletten wach gehalten.

> Die Tabletten halten *einen* wach.

An alternative would be impersonal *you*:

> Die Tabletten halten *dich* wach.

(Impersonal meaning that *dich* does not refer to the addressee, but to anyone taking these tablets.)

Your initial hypothesis that the sentence is a relative clause was correct. As usual, the verb is key for interpreting the sentence correctly: with *halten* in final position, the sentence needs a suitable element in first position, i.e. a subordinating conjunction or a relative pronoun. This prohibits interpreting *die einen* as a unit. With *wach halten* being transitive, *die* is interpreted as the subject and *einen* as the object.

A beautiful example with alternating *man* and forms of *ein-*:

> Manchmal liest **man** ein Buch und ist restlos begeistert. **Man** kommt ins Schwärmen und erst da fällt **einem** auf, dass **man** wirklich nicht weiß, was **einen** daran jetzt genau begeistert. ([hr2.de](https://www.hr2.de/podcasts/pollatscheks-kanon-muriel-spark-bringt-es-auf-den-punkt,audio-38988.html))

Comment: I like this explanation. My translation, trying to keep the German word order which is rather unnatural in English: "They, in the best case, keep you awake all night, and in the worst case, send you to the emergency room."

Answer (score 2):

You're quite right that it could mean "the ones", when *einen* would would refer to the pills:

> *Die einen halten einen wach, die anderen machen schläfrig.*

But in this context, the *einen* is used in exactly the way I used the second *einen* above: as the accusative of *einer*, which is an indefinite pronoun here.  Somewhat like "one":

> All pills have different contents.  Keeping *one* awake in the best case, and bringing one into the ER in the worst case.

The complicated thing is that this is prefixed with *die* -- this is a separated relative sentence, linking to *die Tabletten*, as you rightly note as well in the beginning:

> *Die Tabletten, **die einen wach halten**, gibt es in allen möglichen Formen und Farben.*

> The pills, **which keep one awake**, exist in all shapes and colors.

This is not a weird construction, though, it feels natural in the flow of information given here.

(Or, as Thorsten noted, *die* could refer to the *Zusatzstoffe*, too -- but I'd say that's ambiguous.)